# kinetic.d.ts for plugin label missing

Tags: typescript, kineticjs

I downloaded Kinetic.d.ts from [Kinectic.d.ts](http://kineticjstypescript.codeplex.com/)

It's missing Label plugin so I'm trying to create it.

I created:

```
class Label extends Group
{
    constructor(config: LabelConfig);
    setText(text: Text);
    getText(): Text;
    setRect(rect: LabelRect);
    getRect(): LabelRect;
}

class LabelRect extends Shape
{
    constructor(config: LabelRectConfig);
    setPointerDirection(pointerDirection: string);
    setPointerWidth(pointerWidth: number);
    setPointerHeight(pointerHeight: number);
    setCornerRadius(cornerRadius: number);
    getPointerDirection(): string;
    getPointerWidth(): number;
    getPointerHeight(): number;
    getCornerRadius(): number;
}

interface LabelConfig extends DrawOptionsConfig, ObjectOptionsConfig
{
    rect: LabelRect;
    text: Text;
}

interface LabelRectConfig extends DrawOptionsConfig, ObjectOptionsConfig
{
    pointerDirection?: string;
    pointerWidth?: number;
    pointerHeight?: number;
    cornerRadius?: number;
}
```

I'm getting this error (I formatted the error for reading purposes):

```
Error   1   Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target:
Could not apply type 'LabelConfig' to argument 1, which is of type 
'{ 
    x: number; 
    y: number; 
    opacity: number; 
    listening: bool; 
    text: 
    { 
        text: string; 
        fontFamily: string; 
        fontSize: number; 
        padding: number; 
        fill: string; 
    }; 
    rect: 
    { 
        fill: string; 
        pointerDirection: string; 
        pointerWidth: number; 
        pointerHeight: number; 
        lineJoin: string; 
    }; 
}'
```

I'm instantiating the label like:

```
var labelNumerator = new Kinetic.Label(
    {
        x: LEFT_MARGIN + numerator.getTextWidth() + 50,
        y: numerator.getY() + 5,
        opacity: 0.75,
        listening: false,
        text: {
            text: 'Numerator',
            fontFamily: FONT,
            fontSize: LABEL_FONT_SIZE,
            padding: LABEL_PADDING,
            fill: LABEL_TEXT_COLOR
        },
        rect: {
            fill: LABEL_BACKGROUND_COLOR,
            pointerDirection: 'left',
            pointerWidth: LABEL_FONT_SIZE + LABEL_PADDING * 2,
            pointerHeight: LABEL_FONT_SIZE + LABEL_PADDING * 2,
            lineJoin: 'round'
        }
    }
);
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I can't see anything wrong when comparing that input to the interfaces you have declared, so perhaps you're missing a property that is required on one of those interfaces that `LabelConfig` or `LabelRect` or `Text` extends. One way to check might be to create a dummy class which `implements` `LabelConfig` and see if the compiler points out some missing properties (you might have to drill down and do this for `LabelRect` and `Text` as well).

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are confusing classes with interfaces. The config object needs to be an interface since it is just a property bag (without implementation i.e. functions). You need to use Config objects instead of classes.

As soon as you declared the following as a class:

```
class LabelRect extends Shape
{
    constructor(config: LabelRectConfig);
    setPointerDirection(pointerDirection: string);
    setPointerWidth(pointerWidth: number);
    setPointerHeight(pointerHeight: number);
    setCornerRadius(cornerRadius: number);
    getPointerDirection(): string;
    getPointerWidth(): number;
    getPointerHeight(): number;
    getCornerRadius(): number;
}
```

You went down the wrong path. Because LabelRect is required by your config interface:

```
interface LabelConfig extends DrawOptionsConfig, ObjectOptionsConfig
{
    rect: LabelRect;
```

This means that would need to provide ALL these functions (and those in the base class) when calling your constructor:

```
constructor(config: LabelConfig);
```

You need to look at the documentation and figure out how you would get it to work with *just* interfaces at the right places.

***The following works*** But may be incorrect, Read the documentation (in particular for setRect / getRect) :

```
/// <reference path="kinetic.d.ts" />

declare module Kinetic {

    class Label extends Group {
        constructor(config: LabelConfig);
        setText(text: Text);
        getText(): Text;
        setRect(rect: LabelRectConfig);
        getRect(): LabelRectConfig;
    }

    class LabelRect extends Shape {
        constructor(config: LabelRectConfig);
        setPointerDirection(pointerDirection: string);
        setPointerWidth(pointerWidth: number);
        setPointerHeight(pointerHeight: number);
        setCornerRadius(cornerRadius: number);
        getPointerDirection(): string;
        getPointerWidth(): number;
        getPointerHeight(): number;
        getCornerRadius(): number;
    }

    interface LabelRectConfig extends RectConfig{

    }

    interface LabelConfig extends DrawOptionsConfig, ObjectOptionsConfig
    {
        rect: LabelRectConfig;
        text: TextConfig;
    }

    interface LabelRectConfig
    {
        pointerDirection?: string;
        pointerWidth?: number;
        pointerHeight?: number;
        cornerRadius?: number;
    }
}


var labelNumerator = new Kinetic.Label(
    {
        x: LEFT_MARGIN + numerator.getTextWidth() + 50,
        y: numerator.getY() + 5,
        opacity: 0.75,
        listening: false,
        text: {
            text: 'Numerator',
            fontFamily: FONT,
            fontSize: LABEL_FONT_SIZE,
            padding: LABEL_PADDING,
            fill: LABEL_TEXT_COLOR
        },
        rect: {
            fill: LABEL_BACKGROUND_COLOR,
            pointerDirection: 'left',
            pointerWidth: LABEL_FONT_SIZE + LABEL_PADDING * 2,
            pointerHeight: LABEL_FONT_SIZE + LABEL_PADDING * 2,
            lineJoin: 'round',
            width: 999, // Need to specify as not optional 
            height: 999, // Need to specify as not optional
        }
    }
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

BASarat

Thanks for responding.  After reading your comments I implemented your suggestions.  Unfortunately it still didn't work.  After troubleshooting some more I discoverd that the Kinectic.d.ts I was using had Kinetic.Text.padding as a string.

```
padding?: string;
```

I reviewed the Text.js file from Kinetic and it has padding as a number set as the default.

```
Kinetic.Node.addGetterSetter(Kinetic.Text, 'padding', 0);
```

So I changed TextConfig from padding?: string; to

Answer (score 0):

oops....I accidently submitted without finishing my answer...

So I changed TextConfig from

```
padding?: string;
```

to

```
padding? number;
```

This seemed to fix the problem.

I did make some small changes to the code you suggested.

```
class Label extends Group
{
    constructor(config: LabelConfig);
    setText(text: TextConfig);
    getText(): TextConfig;
    setRect(rect: LabelRectConfig);
    getRect(): LabelRectConfig;
}

interface LabelConfig extends DrawOptionsConfig, ObjectOptionsConfig
{
    rect: LabelRectConfig;
    text: TextConfig;
}

interface LabelRectConfig extends DrawOptionsConfig, ObjectOptionsConfig
{
    width?: number;
    height?: number;
    pointerDirection?: string;
    pointerWidth?: number;
    pointerHeight?: number;
    cornerRadius?: number;
}
```

This seems to work.  What do you think?